# how receiver app receives the url from sender app in chrome-cast

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

My question is straightforward..

When we select any url for media from sender app, and click on cast icon that video is getting played. As all of us know that chrome-cast supports `HTML5 <video> tag` which needs any `URI` to play video. So when we select any `URL` from  sender app, so `<video>` is getting it as `src` attribute in it and plays it.

```
<html>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/js/receiver/1.0/cast_receiver.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(0);

    // Initialize and start the media playing receiver
    var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver(
        'YOUR_APP_ID_HERE', 
        [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE],
        "",
        5);
    var remoteMedia = new cast.receiver.RemoteMedia();
    remoteMedia.addChannelFactory(
        receiver.createChannelFactory(cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE));

    receiver.start();

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var elem = document.getElementById('vid');
      remoteMedia.setMediaElement(elem);

      var checkStatus = function() {
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
        var st = remoteMedia.getStatus()['state'];

        if( st == 0 || remoteMedia.getStatus()['current_time'] == 0 ) {
            status.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            if( st == 1 && remoteMedia.getStatus()['current_time'] > 0 ) {
                status.innerHTML = 'Paused...';
                status.style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                status.innerHTML = remoteMedia.getStatus()['current_time'];
                status.style.display = 'none';
                elem.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
      }
      setInterval(checkStatus, 1000);
    });
  </script>
  <title>Media Player App</title>
  <body>
    <video id="vid"
           style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%">
    <div id="status" style="display:none; font-size:300%; position:absolute;top:40%;left:40%;">
      <img src="/images/chrome_loading.gif" width="60%">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So here my question is in `receiver.html` file, we are not providing any `src` attribute to `<video>` So which [Receiver API](https://developers.google.com/cast/reference/receiver/jsdoc/) is being called to perform this action??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines in your receiver identify and set the "video" element for the library:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('vid');
remoteMedia.setMediaElement(elem);
```

and the rest is handled by the javascript library that you include in your receiver (i.e. cast_receiver.js)